# How to write Ackermann Function iteratively?

Tags: c, algorithm, ackermann

I wrote a recursive version of Ackermann Function, and it worked properly:

```
int ackermann_r(int m, int n) {
    if(m == 0) {
        return n + 1;
    } else if(n == 0) {
        return ackermann_r(m - 1, 1);
    } else {
        return ackermann_r(m - 1, ackermann_r(m, n - 1));
    }
}
```

Then I tried to rewrite the code iteratively:

(I don't know how to use 2D array using malloc, so you could feel the code is dirty...)

```
int ackermann_i(int m, int n) {
    int* A = (int*) malloc((m+1) * (n+1) * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                A[i*(n+1) + j] = j + 1;
            } else if(j == 0) {
                A[i*(n+1) + j] = A[(i-1)*(n+1) + 1];
            } else {
                A[i*(n+1) + j] = A[(i-1)*(n+1) + A[i*(n+1) + (j-1)]];
            }
        }
    }
    return A[m*(n+1) + n];
}
```

But the iterative version printed a wrong answer. For example:

```
m: 3
n: 2
recursive: 29
iterative: 3
```

Why my iterative code doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Undefined behaviour

Unfortunately, your code shows undefined behaviour due to access on an uninitialized value and out-of-bounds access. The simplest test that shows this behaviour is `m = 1, n = 0`. This indicates only two iterations of the outer loop and one iteration of the inner loop and thus is easier to analyze:

```
int ackermann_i(int m, int n) {
    int* A = (int*) malloc((m+1) * (n+1) * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                A[i*(n+1) + j] = j + 1;              //       (1)
            } else if(j == 0) {
                A[i*(n+1) + j] = A[(i-1)*(n+1) + 1]; //       (2)
            } else {
                A[i*(n+1) + j] = A[(i-1)*(n+1) + A[i*(n+1) + (j-1)]]; // (3)
            }
        }
    }
    return A[m*(n+1) + n];
}
```

So let's iterate by hand:

- `i = 0, j = 0`. We enter `(1)` and set `A[0 + 0] = 1`.
- `i = 1, j = 0`. We enter `(2)` and set `A[2 + 0] = A[0 + 1]`.
- there's always at least `j == 0`, so we don't care about `(3)`.

But there's the issue: we never set `A[0 + 1]`. That value *might* be zero, it might as well be something else at random; undefined behaviour ensues. Even worse, our `A` is not large enough: `(m+1)*(n+1)` is only `2` here, so `A[2]` is an out-of-bound array access.

This indicate two issues:

- our allocated memory isn't large enough and may never be, as the inner term in `a(m, a(m-1,n))` can grow much larger than `n`.
- if we had a solution for that, we'd need to handle the trivial cases first, e.g.

  ```
  for(int j = 0; j <= (n+1); ++j) {
      A[0 + j] = j + 1;          // set all A[i,j] where i = 0
  }
  ```

## A deeper issue with the algorithm

There is however one deeper issue. Your code implies that the Ackermann function can be calculated in [θ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)(m * n). [That's however impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Proof_that_the_Ackermann_function_is_not_primitive_recursive). Instead, you  need at least a stack or something similar that can grow in size to calculate the result. [This implementation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742322/how-to-rewrite-ackermann-function-in-non-recursive-style#10744545) provides some inspiration.